# Java static predicate naming convention

Tags: java, kotlin, static, predicate

Let's say I want to write `isSubdirectory` static function in my `FileUtils` helper class. This function would look like:

```java
class FileUtils {
  public static boolean isSubdirectory(File child, File parent) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Or I could flip `parent` and `child` parameters:

```java
class FileUtils {
  public static boolean isSubdirectory(File parent, File child) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And I cannot choose which order is right...

In Kotlin there would not be any doubts: just declare extension function:

```
fun File.isSubdirectory(parent: File) {
  // ...
}
```

With an eye on kotlin I have invented mnemonic rule: first parameter in static function should be considered as `this` (I'm not the first who invented this rule. I saw many people also using it). So in this example I'd prefer placing `child` as first parameter.

But the question is: is this rule is already formalized and has well known name? I've tired to repeat this rule to people who don't know it and I wish I could simply refer to this rule by it's name.

Comment: I think the same *practice* is applied in Java too, like (`BiPredicate<String, String> bp = String::equals;` - `.equals` called on first string)... But no idea whether this has been named.

Comment: The java.io.File class is obsolete.  You should be using [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead.  If you do that, your method won’t be needed, as there is already [Path.startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith%28java.nio.file.Path%29) (which tests for ancestry and is *not* the same as String.startsWith).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a name or any real formalization. At best, it's just a common convention to have the first parameter look like the `this`.
Although rarest, the "this last" convention also exists, more in C and early C++ (Example: stdio with fread/fwrite)

There also exist conventions based on the argument type; for example promoting the following order:

- Collection and other objects with generic parameters
- Arrays of objects
- Objects without generics
- String
- Arrays of primitive types, e.g. `byte[]`
- double, float
- long, int, short, byte
- boolean

There also exist the more or less exact opposite order. Other conventions also tend to group arguments by their type, prefering `method(String, String, int, int)` rather than `method(String, int, String, int)`.

As you can see, there are a lot of conventions that exist. I'm not sure that any of them has a name, and that any is really much more used than any other.
It isn't as clear as camelCase vs. snake_case for example, which almost no one contradict.

What you can keep from all that is the following: put the arguments in the order that looks the most logical and straightforward to you.
The most important is to stay consist in the entire project, i.e. don't write `isFileX(a,b)` and then `isFileY(b,a)` for example, a fortiori if the two methods are in the same class.
IN case of doubt, don't hesitate to ask other people working on your project what they think is the best.

For your particular case, it's reasonnable to put child first because of the "this first" rule, but it's as reasonnable to put the parent first, as it's also a common convention for example in GUI frameworks.
It's up to you to decide.

Comment: Seems like no more valuable answer with exact pattern name with appropriate references isn't coming up so marking as right answer. Thanks for a great answer!